# Is there a way to factor $uv-u-v-1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$uv-u-v-1$. I tried $(u+1)(v-1)$ and it's almost correct but I can't quite get it/ This is part of a limit problem I'm doing. Thanks!

Comment: No, it doesn't factor. You can write it as $(u-1)(v-1)-2$, but you can't factor it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This polynomial in $u$ and $v$ is irreducible (not factorable). Observe that since it is degree 2, it can only factor nontrivially as the product of two linear polynomials in $u$ and $v$. So $$uv-u-v-1=(au+bv+c)(du+ev+f)$$ Without loss of generality we can rescale so that $a=1$. Then $d$ must be $0$, so that the product has no $u^2$ term. Since the product is nontrivial, $e$ must now be nonzero, and therefore $b=0$ so that there is no $v^2$ term. Now
$$uv-u-v-1=(u+c)(ev+f)$$ forcing $e$ to equal 1 to mach the coefficient of $uv$. Lastly, to match coefficients on $u$ and $v$, we have $c=f=-1$, but this is in contradiction with the constant term.

Answer (score 4):

Condition for $ax^{2}+by^{2}+2hxy+2gx+2fy+c$ to have linear factors $\left|\array{a&h&g\\h&b&f\\g&f&c}\right|=0$.

In the given expression $a=0,b=0,h=\frac{1}{2},g=\frac{-1}{2},f=\frac{-1}{2},c=-1.$
The  expression does not satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 3):

$$uv - u - v - 1 = (u-1)(v-1) - 2$$

or $$uv - u - v - 1 = u(v-1) - (v + 1)$$

...that's as good as it will get. It cannot be otherwise factored: that is, it cannot be written as a product of factors.

Comment: Ok thank you. But is there a way to know if something is factorable?

Comment: @Ovi: That is a very good question, because the answer in general is very complicated!

Comment: @MJD That's what came to mind for me, too...

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $uv-u-v-1=p(u,v)q(u,v)$ for polynomials $p,q$. Now consider $u=2k,v=2$, so for integer $k>1$.

$$4k-2k-2-1=p(2k,2)q(2k,2)$$
$$2k-3=p(2k,2)q(2k,2)$$

Now $2k-3$ is a prime number for infinitely many values of $k$. So either $p(2k,2)=1$ infinitely often, $p(2k,2)=-1$ infinitely often, $q(2k,2)=1$ infinitely often, or $q(2k,2)=-1$ infinitely often. Wlog, let's say $p(2k,2)$ is constant for infintely many values of $k$. As a polynomial $p(u,v)$ must be constant in $u$.

We could consider $u=2$, $v=2k$, and conclude one of $p,q$ is constant in $v$. But it can't be $p$ or $p$ is outright constant. So $q$ is constant in $v$.

So $uv-u-v-1=p(v)q(u)$. With $u=0$, we find $-v-1=p(v)q(0)$, meaning $p(v)=a\cdot(v+1)$. Similarly using $v=0$, we find $q(u)=b\cdot(u+1)$. So
$$uv-u-v-1=ab(u+1)(v+1)=c(u+1)(v+1)$$
$$uv-u-v-1=c(uv+u+v+1)$$
This is of course impossible since $c$ must be $1$ for the $uv$ terms to agree, but $c$ must be $-1$ for all of the other terms to agree.